# Jenkins error: When trying to install plugin/create new job

Tags: jenkins

When I try to create a Jenkins free Style project I receive Error:

SyntaxError: invalid range in character class
(form not submitted)

Few days ago it was working fine: Today when I try to modify or try to install a plugin it is giving me the same error

Below is the stack trace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to parse JSON:init
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getSubmittedForm(RequestImpl.java:878)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doConfigSubmit(Jenkins.java:2842)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at     

 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of init
at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:919)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1145)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:162)
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:132)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.getSubmittedForm(RequestImpl.java:876)
... 53 more
```

Comment: Do you also get error even when you're trying to run an existing job?

Comment: Actually I tried modifying the work space location (Github)of the existing job and run the same.

Comment: That's ok but do you also get error even when you're trying to run an existing job?

Comment: Yes, even if i want to save some change or run existing i am getting the error.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you try logging in using a different browser and see if you get the same issue?

Comment: same issue is replicated